# jQuery Check if string is in RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to check if `fileExt`is in `avoidExt` and use it in a `if...else` statement.

```
var thisFile=$(this).val();                   //returns "file.jpg"
var fileExt = thisFile.replace(/^.*\./, '');  //return "jpg"
var avoidExt= new RegExp(/(\.|\/)(bat|exe|cmd|sh|php|pl|cgi|386|dll|com|torrent|js|app|jar|pif|vb|vbscript|wsf|asp|cer|csr|jsp|drv|sys|ade|adp|bas|chm|cpl|crt|csh|fxp|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|jse|htaccess|htpasswd|ksh|lnk|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|msc|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|prg|reg|scr|sct|shb|shs|url|vbe|vbs|wsc|wsf|wsh)$/i);
```

Comment: you mean `fileExt` in `thisFile`?

Comment: Remove `(\.|\/)` from the pattern, or make it optional: `[.\/]?`.

Comment: `fileExt` is the files extension like `jpg` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)**

```js
var thisFile = "file.jpg";
var fileExt = thisFile.replace(/^.*\./, ''); //return "jpg"
var avoidExt = new RegExp(/(\.|\/)(bat|exe|cmd|sh|php|pl|cgi|386|dll|com|torrent|js|app|jar|pif|vb|vbscript|wsf|asp|cer|csr|jsp|drv|sys|ade|adp|bas|chm|cpl|crt|csh|fxp|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|jse|htaccess|htpasswd|ksh|lnk|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|msc|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|prg|reg|scr|sct|shb|shs|url|vbe|vbs|wsc|wsf|wsh)$/i);

console.log(avoidExt.test('.' + fileExt) ? 'fileExt is in' : 'fileExt is not in');
```

**UPDATE :**  `IF...ELSE`  format

```js
var thisFile = "file.jpg";
var fileExt = thisFile.replace(/^.*\./, ''); //return "jpg"
var avoidExt = new RegExp(/(\.|\/)(bat|exe|cmd|sh|php|pl|cgi|386|dll|com|torrent|js|app|jar|pif|vb|vbscript|wsf|asp|cer|csr|jsp|drv|sys|ade|adp|bas|chm|cpl|crt|csh|fxp|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|jse|htaccess|htpasswd|ksh|lnk|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|msc|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|prg|reg|scr|sct|shb|shs|url|vbe|vbs|wsc|wsf|wsh)$/i);

if (avoidExt.test('.' + fileExt))
  console.log('fileExt is in')
else
  console.log('fileExt is not in');
```

Or there is no need to extract the extension using regex you can do the following

```js
var thisFile = "file.jpg";
var avoidExt = new RegExp(/(\.|\/)(bat|exe|cmd|sh|php|pl|cgi|386|dll|com|torrent|js|app|jar|pif|vb|vbscript|wsf|asp|cer|csr|jsp|drv|sys|ade|adp|bas|chm|cpl|crt|csh|fxp|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|jse|htaccess|htpasswd|ksh|lnk|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|msc|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|prg|reg|scr|sct|shb|shs|url|vbe|vbs|wsc|wsf|wsh)$/i);

console.log(avoidExt.test(thisFile) ? 'fileExt is in' : 'fileExt is not in');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```js
var thisFile=$(this).val();
var fileExt = thisFile.replace(/^.*\./, '');
var avoidExt= new RegExp(/(\.|\/)(bat|exe|cmd|sh|php|pl|cgi|386|dll|com|torrent|js|app|jar|pif|vb|vbscript|wsf|asp|cer|csr|jsp|drv|sys|ade|adp|bas|chm|cpl|crt|csh|fxp|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|jse|htaccess|htpasswd|ksh|lnk|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|msc|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|prg|reg|scr|sct|shb|shs|url|vbe|vbs|wsc|wsf|wsh)$/i);
if(fileExt.test(avoidExt)){
    console.log("EXIST");  

}else{
    console.log("NOT EXIST");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this will help**

```
var thisFile = $(this).val();
// var fileExt = thisFile.replace(/^.*\./, ''); doesn't need this line
var avoidExt= new RegExp(/(\.|\/)(bat|exe|cmd|sh|php|pl|cgi|386|dll|com|torrent|js|app|jar|pif|vb|vbscript|wsf|asp|cer|csr|jsp|drv|sys|ade|adp|bas|chm|cpl|crt|csh|fxp|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|jse|htaccess|htpasswd|ksh|lnk|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|msc|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|prg|reg|scr|sct|shb|shs|url|vbe|vbs|wsc|wsf|wsh)$/i);
if(avoidExt.test(thisFile)){
    // exist
}else{
    // doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not necessary to create a `RegExp` object, you can use a regexp literal:

```
var fileExt = $(this).val().replace(/^.*\./, '');
var avoidExt = /(bat|exe|cmd|sh|php|pl|cgi|386|dll|com|torrent|js|app|jar|pif|vb|vbscript|wsf|asp|cer|csr|jsp|drv|sys|ade|adp|bas|chm|cpl|crt|csh|fxp|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|jse|htaccess|htpasswd|ksh|lnk|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|msc|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|prg|reg|scr|sct|shb|shs|url|vbe|vbs|wsc|wsf|wsh)/i;

if(fileExt.text(avoidExt)){
  // exist
} else {
  // doesn't exist
}
```